# ASP.NET URL rewriting and redirecting

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, url-rewriting

I am trying to wrap my head around a URL rewrtie / redirect project I need to work on. We currently have this url: `http://www.example.com/Details/Detail.aspx?param1=8&param2=12345`

Here is what the rewritten URL will look like: `http://www.example.com/Param1/8/Param2/12345`

I am using the ISAPI_Rewrite filter to allow for the "nice" url and make the page think it is still using the old url. That works fine.

Now, I need to redirect users, if they use the old URL, to the new URL. I figure I would need to use a combination of the filter and an HTTPModule / Handler to perform the redirect.

Any ideas?

Comment: What I may end up doing is having a HttpHandler inspect the URL for the old version and redirect to the new one.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [IIS URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to go down the `System.Web.Routing` (or use [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/)) path then I would have a look at [this link](http://runtingsproper.blogspot.com/2009/11/advanced-url-rewriting-for-rest-of-us.html).

Comment: Well, I have read that, but that only helps me with the rewrite of the URL, not the redirection that would need to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Using a HttpHandler would be your best bet. That way, you will be able to track all incoming requests, filter out the old format URLs and redirect them to the correct pages.